# How to return a value in html from angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I m downloading a file using AngularJS and java from server. Because by Ajax `GET` request doesn't support downloading a file using jax-rs so I am using an alternative approach for it.

Select the different field from UI, on click submit I want to create a url at app.js and want to assign it's return value to href so that href tag force window to open with a popup to download

```
<input type="button" onclick="location.href=GetUrl();" value="Submit"/>
```

function in `App.js` is

```
  $scope.GetUrl = function() {
      // do some computation;
      return "url"
  }
```

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 1):

Change `onclick` to `ng-click` to access scope functions

```
<input type="button" ng-click="GetUrl();" value="Submit"/>


  $scope.GetUrl = function() {
      // do some computation;
      // here assign the url to location.href
      location.href = url;
  }
```

Comment: in this case, the HTML would be `<input type="button" ng-click="GetUrl()" />`

Comment: Actually I put it in the code but forgot to mention it in the `` back-quotes. So, it was disappear. Anyway, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change `onclick` to `ng-click`. `onclick` does not know `$scope` bindings. So, it won't call the function `GetUrl`.

```
<input type="button" ng-click="location.href=GetUrl();" value="Submit"/>
```